# Transform OTM for Problem π to DTM ∈ DSPACE(n)

Tags: turing-machines, decision-problem, space-complexity, oracle-machines, proof-assistants

Given an Oracle Turing machine ($OTM$) that solves Problem π in max. 2n space, so $O(n)$ space and $O(n^2)$ time.
Is there a DTM that can solve $π$ in $O(n)$ space if time doesn't matter? (The length of an instance $I$ of $π$ is n)

I would say the answer is yes.
Construction: We already have a DTM M', which can verify a suggested solution given by the Oracle module for $I$ in $O(n)$ space. So basically, we just need to feed M' all possible suggestions for a solution to an Instance I deterministically.

How should I go on to formally prove this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the oracle.  If $\pi$ is solved by the OTM using an oracle for a non-computable problem (non-decidable language), then there might not be a DTM that can solve $\pi$ without an oracle. There is no guarantee that you can verify the response from the oracle.